# PHP error adding +1 value to text file

Tags: php

My current code works fine but for some reason it resets the value.txt to 0 and starts over.
The .txt file value.txt contains a number example 123 and after the PHP code processes it should show 124 and continue this way.

The issue that I have right now is that the value.txt resets at a random point.

```
$oldvalue= file_get_contents("value.txt");
$newvalue = $oldvalue + 1;
file_put_contents("value.txt", $newvalue);
```

Answer (score 3):

If there are some characters in your file that are not nummeric you have a string and can't increment it.

Perhaps you should cast your value first to an integer.

```
$newvalue = intval($oldvalue) + 1;
```

or

```
$newvalue = (int)$oldvalue + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$newvalue = (int)$oldvalue + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

It may by possible if somehow you file got 222 permission that allow to write into the file, but does not allow to read it.

Check permissions, and be sure that error reporting is enabled to see warnings.

Comment: The file currently has 777 permission :) and there are no errors being reported

Comment: Does somebody else writing to the file?

Comment: No this is the only thing that writes to the file.

Comment: Try to log each step in the log file. Maybe it will help to find the reason.